# How to resolve iphone app rejection on 2.2 Apps that exhibit bugs will be rejected

Tags: ios, iphone, appstore-approval

I submitted the iphone app to the app store, It was rejected for the point from the resolution center:

2.2 Apps that exhibit bugs will be rejected

> We found that your app exhibited one or more bugs, when reviewed on iPhone 4 running iOS 5.1.1, on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

I have not used any of the network connection related codes. This app will simply create a PDF and send via default mail composer(MFMailComposerViewController) that's it..

Is there any possibility to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you tested your app extensively, on an iPhone 4 running 5.1.1? If not, start there.

Comment: No, But I tested in iPhone 4 with iOS 5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MFMailComposerViewController is network related code. You need to handle the fail condition with what to do if the app is not connected to a network and so it can't send it's email. I suggest testing your application to see how it handles not being on a data network.

You can handle what happens when the email is not sent properly in the delegate method.

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error;
{
    if (result == MFMailComposeResultFailed) {
         //Add error handling here
    }
}
```